# Cannot add instance of type 'MultiBinding' to a collection of type 'DoubleCollection'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

**Error:** I am trying to use a IMultiValueConverter I wrote, but Intellisense is giving me this error **"Cannot add instance of type 'MultiBinding' to a collection of type 'DoubleCollection'. Only items of type 'double' are allowed."**

**Q:** I do not understand what this error means. I've used other converters to modify the StrokeDashArray properties in other paths; however, I am not sure how to use a multibinding. Can someone explain why I am getting this error, and how I remove this error?

**Details:** The converter is named "DashedWhenValue1ArrayEqualsValue2ArrayConverter" and I have defined it above as a StaticResource. Here are the interesting parts of my converter

```
. . . 
public DoubleCollection DoubleCollectionWhenEqual { get; set; }
public DoubleCollection DoubleCollectionWhenNotEqual { get; set; }
public DoubleCollection DoubleCollectionWhenValueIsNull { get; set; }

. . .

public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{

  if (values == null || values.Length < 2)
  {
    return this.DoubleCollectionWhenValueIsNull;
  }

  if ( !(values[0] is Array) || !(values[1] is Array) )
  {
    return this.DoubleCollectionWhenNotEqual;
  }

  object[] array1 = values[0] as object[];
  object[] array2 = values[1] as object[];

  if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
  {
    return this.DoubleCollectionWhenNotEqual;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
  {
    if (array1[i] != array2[i])
    {
      return this.DoubleCollectionWhenNotEqual;
    }
  }

  return this.DoubleCollectionWhenEqual;

}
. . .
```

I use my converter in the view here

```
<Path x:Name="some_Path" Data="M7,4.167 L7,162.08887" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-391.5,-871" StrokeStartLineCap="Square" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="#FF33CC33" StrokeThickness="10" Width="10.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Height="167.167" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
      <Path.StrokeDashArray>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DashedWhenValue1ArrayEqualsValue2ArrayConverter}"> <!-- Error starts here -->
          <Binding Path="ModelViewProperty1" />
          <Binding Path="ModelViewProperty2" />
        </MultiBinding> <!-- Error ends here -->
      </Path.StrokeDashArray>
    </Path>
```

Comment: The line where the <MultiBinding> is declared

Comment: Is it just an intellisense problem or does it actually fail when you run your app? What happens if you restart Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate your error in Visual Studio 2015. It does appear to be simply a bug with the XAML editor, not an actual problem with your XAML or converter. When I run the app, I get different dashing depending on whether `ModelViewProperty1` and `ModelViewProperty2` both have values and are equivalent.

So, my advice would be to ignore this particular error.

P.S. Just for fun, here is a more succinct way to write your `Convert` method using LINQ:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var arrays = values
        .OfType<Array>()
        .Select(x => x.OfType<object>())
        .ToList();
    if (arrays.Count != 2) return DoubleCollectionWhenValueIsNull;
    return arrays[0].SequenceEqual(arrays[1]) ? DoubleCollectionWhenEqual : DoubleCollectionWhenNotEqual;
}
```

Comment: I will ignore the error than. Thanks for the Convert tips!